# find without recursion

Tags: unix, find, shell

Is it possible to use the `find` command in some way that it will not recurse into the sub-directories? For example,

```
DirsRoot
  |-->SubDir1
  |    |-OtherFile1
  |-->SubDir2
  |    |-OtherFile2
  |-File1
  |-File2
```

And the result of something like `find DirsRoot --do-not-recurse -type f` will be only `File1, File2`?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

I think you'll get what you want with the `-maxdepth 1` option, based on your current command structure. If not, you can try looking at the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for `find`.

Relevant entry (for convenience's sake):

```
-maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc-
          tories below the command line arguments.   `-maxdepth  0'  means
          only  apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.
```

Your options basically are:

```
# Do NOT show hidden files (beginning with ".", i.e., .*):
find DirsRoot/* -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

Or:

```
#  DO show hidden files:
find DirsRoot/ -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Comment: For the OP's example I think this needs to be `-maxdepth 1` ?

Comment: @Paul R: Actually, that sort of depends on how he wants to handle hidden files, but I've amended my answer nonetheless. For his example `1` is probably what he wants.

Comment: For me,`-maxdepth 0` isn't showing *any* file but `-maxdepth 1` is working as intended, with hidden files being displayed as well.

Comment: @BruceWayne note the `*` in `find DirsRoot/* -maxdepth 0 -type f`. If you leave that out, it won't show any files.

Comment: @mook, Thanks, but I can't remember the original context in which I had this issue, haha.

Comment: Using '*' to omit hidden files displays an error if nothing is found.  I guess you can redirect stedrr to dev/null but this could obscure other issues.  Not sure yet if this is truly useful as a one line solution.

Comment: Caveat: `find DirsRoot/* -maxdepth 0 -type f` prints "No such file or directory" and returns 1 if the directory exists but contains no files. To ignore hidden files and handle existing directory with no files gracefully, use: `find DirsRoot/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/.*'`

Answer (score 37):

I believe you are looking for `-maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 19):

If you look for POSIX compliant solution:

`cd DirsRoot && find . -type f -print -o -name . -o -prune`

**-maxdepth** is not POSIX compliant option.

Comment: thanks for this solution, but can't this be simplified to `find DirsRoot/* -type f -prune`?

Comment: @dokaspar Really great question! (you forgot to insert "-o" before `-prune` btw)

The answer is no, it cannot. To fully understand WHY it cannot be simplified, just emit `set -x` command before emitting the `find DirsRoot/* -type f -o -prune` and you will immediately see it yourself.

The root cause is the limitations of the shell expansion of `DirsRoot/*` expression.

Comment: not working on centos, still doing full recursion at output!!!!   The proper command is `find . -name . -o -prune`

Comment: on Solaris anyway, keeping with DirsRoot as the desired path, you do not need cd ; instead, you can: find DirsRoot/. -type f -print -o -name . -o -prune

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible by using **-maxdepth** option in find command

```
find /DirsRoot/* -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

From the manual

`man find`

> -maxdepth levels
>
> Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the starting-points.
>
> -maxdepth 0
>
> means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.