# for loop in Linux treats pattern as filename when no files exist

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I ran the following in a directory with no files:

```
for file in *.20191017.*;do echo ${file}; done
```

what it returned was this:

```
*.20191017.*
```

which is little awkward since this was just a pattern and not the filename itself.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: What do you intend to do? The purpose of this code is a little unclear to me.

Comment: @user2442590 : It's not awkward, but documented behaviour. You will have to enable `nullglob`, as described in the bash man page.

Answer (score 5):

Found the reason for this anomaly (source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)

You can do filename expansion in loop such as work on all pdf files in current directory:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    echo "Removing password for pdf file - $f"
done
```

However, there is one problem with the above syntax. If there are no pdf files in current directory it will expand to *.pdf (i.e. f will be set to *.pdf”). To avoid this problem add the following statement before the for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: remove all utility bills pdf file password 
shopt -s nullglob # expands the glob to empty string when there are no matching files in the directory.
for f in *.pdf; do
    echo "Removing password for pdf file - $f"
    pdftk "$f" output "output.$f" user_pw "YOURPASSWORD-HERE"
done
```

Comment: Note that this is not an "anomaly". It's expected default behavior. In some cases, it's not helping, though...

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop simply iterates over the words between `in` and `;` (possibly expanded by `bash`). Here, `file` is just the variable name. If you want to iterate between all files that are actually present, you can, for example, add a `if` to check if the `${file}` really exists:

```
for file in *.20191017.*
do
   if [ -e "${file}" ]
   then
      echo ${file}
   fi
done
```

Or you can use, e.g., [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

```
find . -name '*.20191017.*' -maxdepth 1
```

`-maxdepth 1` is to [avoid recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925337/find-without-recursion).

Comment: Found the reason for this anomaly (source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)